# Zoom level difference between Camera1 and Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2

In our application, we support both APIs, Camera and Camera2, for taking pictures. What I noticed is that we are getting different zoom-in depths across both the APIs.

Using Camera1 API, setting the zoom level is straightforward:

```
Camera.Paramenters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setZoom(zoomLevel);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Using Camera2 API, zoom level is set as follows (code taken for standard Camera2 sample application):

```
final int zoomScale = 200;
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, new
     Rect(zoomScale * mZoomLevel, zoomScale * mZoomLevel, mStartBounds.right
     - (zoomScale * mZoomLevel), mStartBounds.bottom - (zoomScale * mZoomLevel)));
```

The Android device I am using has a max zoom value of 4. At zoom level 4, Camera1  seems to zoom in much more than Camera2 (by at least 10%).

I am wondering if I missed something in my calculation or is it just the way Camera2 API has been designed. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you selected the value 200 for zoomScale.  The crop region for camera2 is in the coordinates of the sensor's [active array](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE), so if you want a 2x zoom, you need to set the rectangle to be half the width and height of the active array.

Rough sample code:

```
CameraCharacteristics c = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
Rect activeArray = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
int cropWidth = activeArray.width() / mZoomLevel;
int cropHeight = activeArray.height() / mZoomLevel; 
int cropLeft = (activeArray.width() - cropWidth) / 2;
int cropTop = (activeArray.height() - cropHeight) / 2;
Rect cropRegion = new Rect(cropLeft, cropTop, cropLeft + cropWidth, cropTop + cropHeight)
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, cropRegion);
```